# Getting around GoDaddy shared hosting SSL limitations

Tags: ssl-certificate, godaddy, shared-hosting

GoDaddy shared hosting apparently forces you to buy one of their SSL certs, i.e., you can't use StartSSL and then upload your own.

Is there a way around that, perhaps using .htaccess as described [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500)?  If so, since the FTP login they provide in shared hosting doesn't let you above the visible root, how would I protect the key files?

Comment: Get a better host.

Comment: This helped a great deal. Shame that the moderators considered me too unimportant or too small a human being to think it would help someone. Thank you for helping and asking the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify SSL parameters in a `.htaccess` file. By the time the server knows what directory to look at, SSL negotation is long since finished.

In any event, there is no way around a service requirement anyway. Even if you had some technical means around it, it would still be a requirement, so you couldn't use those means.